# Mapping UID and GID of local user to the mounted NFS share

Tags: nfs, mapping

I have a server with NFSv4.
I am mounting contents of the home folder of remote user to local host.
Able to read and write contents, but when I am checking ownership of files at the mounted volume from the local host, they all belongs to corresponding remote user and group (512).
Is there any way to make it look like they belong to the local user and group (1000) on the local host?

**/etc/exports** on **remote** host (IP is 192.168.1.110)

```
/home/user512 192.168.1.142(rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=512,anongid=512)
```

**/etc/fstab** on **local** host (IP is 192.168.1.142)

```
192.168.1.110:/home/user512    /home/localuser/projects/project512   nfs    rw,hard,intr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768    0       0
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is what idmapping is suppose to do. First of all, enable is on the client and server:

```
# echo N > /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
```

clean idmap cache and restart idmap daemon:

```
# nfsidmap -c
# service rpcidmapd restart
```

Now on server and the client will send instead of numeric IDs string principals like *bob@YOURDOMAIN.COM*. You need to have **bob** account on the both hosts - client and server.

Nevertheless, the numeric ID's can be different.

Comment: Ftr, on nfs server the path is /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping (nfsd, not nfs)

Comment: No service ``rpcidmapd`` on my Linux Mint client.

Comment: Question about this answer: will doing

`echo N > /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable-idmapping`

make this setting permanent, or will I have to reset it every time after reboot?

Comment: Under Ubuntu the service is called `idmapd` instead of `rpcidmapd`

Comment: Debian => idmapd from nfs-common package The service is named `nfs-idmapd`

Comment: On Fedora, the restart command is `systemctl restart nfs-idmap.service`. And on the server side, the path is: `/sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping`; while on the client side it is `/sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping` (that is, with out the 'd' in nfs).

Answer (score 11):

You have all the pieces there. From the exportfs man page, `all_squash` maps all uids and gids to the anonymous versions. What you wrote forced those values to be 512. If you changed to 1000, the nfs server on the remote host would make everything 1000, and access should be granted.

Comment: My uid on the client is 1000, the uid of the user with the same name on the server is 1003. I have tried setting `anonuid=1000,anongid=1000` and `anonuid=1003,anongid=1003` (and restarting the nfsserver, and un/remounting the share) and neither work. Downvoting, because this answer does not seem to work.

Comment: Just to confirm, what are your export and fstab entries?

Comment: `/home/gkistner *(async,rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check)` in exports, and `10.20.118.112:/home/gkistner   /mnt/r2     nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr` in fstab

Answer (score 5):

on your nfs client, edit /etc/idmapd.conf and change

```
[Mapping]

Nobody-User = myappuser
Nobody-Group = myappuser
```

afther this restart the nfs service

Comment: I needed to run `nfsidmap -c` after updating `/etc/idmapd.conf`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix `nobody:nobody` ownership issue over NFS on CentOS 6 (server) + 7 (client) with two changes:

1. Make sure the `/etc/idmapd.conf` `Domain` parameter is the same on server and client
2. Server has an actual user with matching UID and GID to the client

then on the client

```
service nfs restart
```

and remount shares if necessary