# NFS Write Permissions -- ls -l shows I have it; I actually don't

Tags: permissions, nfs

I have an NFS server serving several clients. Permissions work fine with all clients except one. The client mounts the nfs share fine, with permissions all correctly placed to the right users.

Indeed, `ls -l /home/` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x 22 user     user     12288 Jan 27 14:30 user
```

"user" is the mounted drive from the NFS. This is set up so that any user can log into the server and access the NFS immediately (and so that people will actually use it :)

But, when logged into `user`, when I `touch /home/user/test.txt` I get this error:

```
touch: cannot touch `/home/user/test.txt': Permission denied
```

Altering files works the same way. I can create files via sudo, but not by using the user alone (who owns the directory and has read/write access on the folder!).

Server settings:

```
cat /etc/exports

/raid/nfs/home        server1(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/raid/nfs/home        server2(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Again, only one server (of five) has this issue.

Client settings:

```
cat /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
N 

cat /etc/idmapd.conf
[General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /run/rpc_pipefs
# set your own domain here, if id differs from FQDN minus hostname
Domain = localdomain

[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
```

Again, nfs-related settings are identical between clients, but only this client is having this issue. Is there another setting I'm missing here? Any routine checks I can do to spot the error? I'm stumped with this problem, especially since the server lists me as owner, but I apparently do not have ownership.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled on client? Do your UIDs and GIDs match on client and server?

Comment: @FedericoSierra I don't have SELinux installed. The UIDs and GIDs do not match, but the NFS is mapped according to id strings via http://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share. The string-mapped NFS mounts work on every other machine, with different UIDs and GIDs.

Comment: Try run `rpc.idmapd -fvvv` and `rpc.gssd -fvvv` in separate terminals to see what is wrong.

Comment: this in did looks line idmap issue. Is the inmapd.conf file on the server looks the same? what you see with 'ls -ln' ?