# Some users cannot write via NFS, but others can

Tags: permissions, nfs, file-permissions, nfs4

I have an NFS4-mounted `/home` drive, with several different users' home folders in it. I am using `inetd`'s ID-mapping feature (i.e. `NEED_IDMAPD=YES` in `/etc/default/nfs-common`).

The NFS mount and ID-mapping seem to be working properly, because most user accounts can read and write files in their home drives. However, there are a few that get a "Permission denied" error when attempting to write to files in their home directory.

`ls -lA` shows that the permissions and ownership are as expected (i.e. `/home/me` is owned by `me:me` and has owner `rxw` permissions). The users in question are not part of any groups besides their own (i.e. if `me` can't write to `/home/me/foo`, then the output of `groups me` is `me : me`). I don't think that can be the problem, though, because there is at least one user who *can* write to their home dir and who is not a member of any other groups.

This may be related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/662827/nfs-write-permissions-ls-l-shows-i-have-it-i-actually-dont), but that question makes it sound like the problem is with a particular client *machine* rather than a particular user account. (At the moment I am only working with a single client machine.)

Comment: check with wireshark that cedentioals used by write request matches to directory/file owner ship. ( and i guess acl are not used )

Comment: @tigran I did not intend to create acl lists--is there any chance that they were auto-generated somehow? Where can I find them? I don't know anything about Wireshark, but I'll try that.