# NFS nobody issue

Tags: ldap, nfs, nfs4, 389-ds

I am having the nfs nobody issue running Centos 6 . I am running nfsv4 and authenticating users using 389-ds LDAP . The nfs mounts on the client are fine, but I am getting the folling error:

`rpc_idmapd nss_getpwnnam name 'uid' does not map into domain 'domain of server'`

where uid is a value like 1005 and domain is the domain of the server

I have tried the nfsidmap -c on the the client and have made sure that the Domain= option is set to the same domain on both server and client.

the rpcidmap is running along with all the normal NFS services. How do I troubleshoot this issue further ?

Any help or suggestions will be really appreciated

Sincerely
Joshua Lobo

Comment: "are file" in your third sentence is important to your problem statement, but I'm not sure what it means. Is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry that was a type I meant are fine

Comment: check this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share/632315#632315

Comment: SELinux enabled or disabled?

Comment: Selinux is disabled.i know it's bad practice but It took a very long time to enable it again so I left it off

Comment: do the nfs server and the nfs client see the same user when you run getent passwd 1005 on both? Because what you are seeing looks like an id mapping problem

Comment: Yes naxto asenjo when I run getent passwd I can see the users of the ldap . I can authenticate too .But I had to change the ownership of all the files for a particular user manually using chown .It seems to me also like an idmap problem but I am out of ideas on how to solve it.Has anyone had any luck updating nfs_utils i am running   nfs-utiils 1:1.2.3-70 on the client