# NFS mounts folder with NOBODY:NOBODY permissions

Tags: nfs, mount, nobody

I have a CentOS 6 server with NFS installed. In my `/etc/exports` file:

```
/shares/nfs 10.0.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

`exportfs -a` was done.

On my clients I have this in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
10.0.X.XX:/shares/nfs    /mnt/fs    nfs    hard,intr,retrans=2,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,noatime,timeo=600,nosuid   0 0
```

One client mounts the folder just fine, the other gives `nobody:nobody` user and permission to the files and therefore my applications can't use it? Why is this hapening? The UIDs are the same on both clients and the server and we don't use domain names, only IP addresses.

Comment: First check the `/etc/idmap.conf` file on the server and clients and compare them. Especially the `Domain` at the beginning. If you have no luck, mount it as NFSv3 and add `vers=3,hard,...` to your `/etc/fstab` line.

Comment: `[General]
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nobody
[Translations]
Method = nsswitch`

This is all I have on my server. The exact same is on the clients..

Adding vers=3 didn't fix it, it just crashes the mount.

Comment: Hm, strange. Did you restart the `nfs` service already. Also try to `nfsidmap -c ` before restarting and remounting on the clients.

Comment: Yes, restarted everything

Comment: have a look at this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share/632315#632315