# Same NFS share on different clients with different local users

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, fstab, netapp

I have a NFS share on Netapp that is mounted on a RHEL client and I've set its owner and group owner from this client with chown command. User and group are local on this server. I mount the same share on another RHEL client but the user and group that can read and write must be different and local on this second server.
How can I obtain it?

Comment: there are user/uid translations available for NFSv4 (which deals with names, not ids). examples: https://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share , https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=66959 . NFSv4 compatibility with Netapp might give additional challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Ownership of files can't be split like that. The files on the share can only have one owner (UID) and one group (GID). The *names* of those groups could be different on different clients (e.g. UID 1000 is "smith" on one client and "jones" on another), but the actual UID/GID *values* are stored on the NFS server file system and will be the same for all clients.

If you want to have common access across multiple clients with local users, then you'll have to have common definitions of groups on all clients (e.g. the "dummy" group has GID=1001 on all clients). The members of the group could be defined locally.